# Not sure how to split up different categories of functions into different files | C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've been programming this app for quite a while now and have so many functions that I've been trying to avoid clustered together in one blob of code.

I'm relatively new to C++ and I think I understand header files and how to use them properly. But I've run into a slightly more complex problem that deals with private classes. Whenever I try to put these functions in different files and make headers for them I get a lot of errors. I want to keep the wxFrame class in the main.cpp file, but I also need the functions inside it to be defined outside of the file. I could really use some help.

main.cpp

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame{
    public:
        MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
        
        

    private:
        void Carfunc();

        void Busfunc1(); 
        void Busfunc2(); 
        void Busfunc3();
```

BusFunctions.cpp

```
void MyFrame::Busfunc1(){
// do stuff here
}

void MyFrame::Busfunc2(){
// do stuff here
}

void MyFrame::Busfunc3(){
// do stuff here
}
```

CarFunctions.cpp

```
void MyFrame::Carfunc(){
// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: You are getting close to posing a question ... but ... what is it exactly?

Comment: You need to put `class MyFrame : public wxFrame{ ... };` in a header that your cpp files include. You can't have it in main.cpp and use in other cpp files. Remember you include header files but not .cpp files.

Comment: What errors do you get?  [Edit] your question with the exact error messages you're getting.

Comment: *Why* do you want to keep the `MyFrame` definition in `main.cpp`?

Comment: A more common split would be 1 header and 1 cpp file per class although nothing forces you to use only 1 cpp file per class.

Comment: Maybe you want a class Bus { ...}; and class Car { ...}; instead of putting all code in the MyFrame / GUI class.

Comment: If you have a few lines code, for example, you might want to keep in a single `.cpp` file the class and its code for `MyFrame`. Usually you split into many files when you have a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways you can do it.
one is to have those methods (functions) to be defined in a Bus and a Car class.

then `Busfunc1()` in `MyFrame` for example can do `return bus.func1()`
`Busfunc2()` in `MyFrame` can do `return bus.func2()`
`Carfunc()` in `MyFrame` can do `return car.func()`
and so on...
or you can simply make the car and bus on MyFrame public. so that MyFrame has a car, and that car has the Carfunc() instead. and MyFrame has a bus too, and that bus has all the busfuncs instead of the MyFrame.

there is at least 4-5 other ways you can do it, including static methods, inheritance... they would all end up organizing your code in different files. it all depends on what you are trying to achieve. what is the real requirement? for sure, organizing code in general is always good, but what is Busfunc2? What is Carfunc anyway?

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT place the Class Declaration in `main.cpp`
when you do that `CarFunctions.cpp` Don't know the class `MyFrame` exist (same for BusFunctions.cpp) and the compiler will complain!

rather, I would suggest to stick to common conventions and:

1. create a header file named `MyFrame.hpp` for the declaration of class `MyFrame`.
2. create a single source file `MyFrame.cpp` and put all implementations there.

> If you insist on splitting the same classe's implementations, then
> create something like `MyFrame_Car.cpp` and `MyFrame_Bus.cpp`

3. add `#include "MyFrame.hpp"` to any module that needs `MyFrame`
   (MyFrame.cpp needs them too)
4. link all the modules (cpp files) together.

```cpp
// MyFrame.hpp
class MyFrame : public wxFrame{
    public:
        MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
        
        

    private:
        void Carfunc();

        void Busfunc1(); 
        void Busfunc2(); 
        void Busfunc3(); 
...
...
}
```

```cpp
// MyFrame_Bus.cpp
void MyFrame::Busfunc1(){
// do stuff here
}

void MyFrame::Busfunc2(){
// do stuff here
}

void MyFrame::Busfunc3(){
// do stuff here
}
```

```cpp
// MyFrame_Car.cpp
void MyFrame::Carfunc(){
// do stuff here
}
```